# How can I get the front page size of website using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to check the front page size of any website using PhantomJS. Antone help me how?

Comment: In what sense? In PhantomJS, you determine the viewport size.

Comment: Sorry, but what I want is to get the page weight of the website. To know how much the size of the website page.

Comment: for example in normal Google Chrome Browser, there's a Developer Tools under Network panel there's a calculation of file in DOMContentLoaded you'll find the value of transferred, which is the size of the page. I want to get the data of transferred using PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your page is opening without issues, you can set [`Page.prototype.onResourceReceived`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) callback (which has a `bodySize` property in the response corresponding to the `Content-Length` response header):

```
page.onResourceReceived = function (resp) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));//check resp.bodySize
};
```